# Visual Basic login form and SQL database

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create a login form using Visual Basic and am using an SQL database to store the data. How do I compare what the user inputs into the text box, with data from the database?

I have created a service based database in Visual Studio 2015 and have created the table but I have no idea on how to connect it to the database. Do I have to make use of data sets?I have watched many videos on You Tube and have searched the internet but nothing seems to be working.

I would be grateful if someone could walk me through some steps.

Cheers!

Comment: What code have you created so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you're asking is "How do I authenticate a user?" which is a MASSIVE topic. You're on the right track with searching the internet. Here are some links which outline some auth methods that might be particularly helpful:

(Database Creation Sample
The application leads you through the steps in creating and populating the database)

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Creation-Sample-a4dfb405/sourcecode?fileId=46201&pathId=293681583

(Implementing Custom Authentication and Authorization)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172766(v=vs.100).aspx

You can find many, many more by searching things like "how to authenticate a user in visual basic"